# is there enter and leave event on TextBox - asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there enter and leave event on an asp.net TextBox?

I need that when i click on the TextBox, the TextBox color will be yellow and when I leave the color will be white.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery to handle this, there are two events that you need. onfocus and onblur.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').focus(function () {
        $(this).addClass('yellowBackground');
    });
    $('input').blur(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('yellowBackground');
    });
});
```

Here is the CSS incase you were wondering:

```
<style type="text/css">
.yellowBackground 
{
    background:yellow;
}
</style>
```

**Edit**

The keyword "event" in your question made me originally suggest using javascript, but this can be achieved in CSS using the `:focus` selector:
`input:focus { background-color: yellow }`

https://jsfiddle.net/3dLp0f03/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Javascript for that.
Unlike the `Click` (ASP.NET) event, which can be handled on the server, mouse enter and leave events are handled on the client side, via a script language such as Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have considerable backwards compatibility in this regard, you will need to react to the `onfocus` and `onblur` events of the `input` element produced by the `Textbox` control.

However, since it's not likely to be vital to have it work on older browsers (being a decorative matter) it can be done more easily simply with the CSS:

```
input:focus { background: yellow; }
```

One can easily extend this further to only apply to some such elements.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [onblur and onfocus](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_input.asp)

[onblur Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

> The onblur event occurs when an object
>   loses focus.

[onfocus Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp)

> The onfocus event occurs when an
>   object gets focus.

Answer (score 0):

try here: http://forums.devarticles.com/net-development-43/setting-textbox-focus-in-c-56162.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Change Textbox/Input background color on focus](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/inputBgOnFocus.aspx)